# Manually installing SonarQube plugins on Docker image

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I want to create my custom SonarQube docker image, with some plugins already installed, but every time I run my container, the plugins are not there. It's like something removes the plugins from `/opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins` and copy the `bundled-plugins` there.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM sonarqube

ENV SONARQUBE_HOME /opt/sonarqube

RUN wget "http://downloads.sonarsource.com/plugins/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-scm-git-plugin/1.1/sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.1.jar" \
    && wget "https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/releases/download/3.12-RC2/sonar-java-plugin-3.12-build4634.jar" \
    && wget "https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/releases/download/1.1-M9/sonar-github-plugin-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" \
    && wget "https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-auth-github/releases/download/1.0-RC1/sonar-auth-github-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" \
    && wget "https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-badges/releases/download/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-badges-1.2.1/qualinsight-sonarqube-badges-1.2.1.jar" \
    && mv *.jar $SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins \
    && ls -lah $SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins
```

I tried listing the folder, and it lists my desired plugins. But if I list the same folder after I started the container, they are gone.

I've also tried removing the `bundled-plugins` with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Sonarqube image uses a *volume* for the `/extensions/` directory, which results in the files in that directory not being stored in the image's filesystem; see the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/442f950dae232fca8e1e919e017270971cee46f6/4.5.6/Dockerfile#L37)

To package those extensions in your image, you need them *outside* of that directory, and copy those files to the `/extensions/` in an entrypoint script, or store your plugins in a separate image, and mount those plugins as a volume when running the image; you can find an example doing that here; https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md

Comment: That solves the issue. Thank you! Btw, where would be the best place to ask that jar files are published as releases in Github? For example, you can download the jar file for this plugin https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-auth-github/releases in the releases section, but not for new releases. Same is happening in most of plugins I've seen.

Comment: Best place to ask that is in the issue tracker of that repository ( and for the other plugins). Check if there isn't an existing feature request already though

Comment: They don't have issues enabled :/

Answer (score 9):

Note the accepted answer is no longer true. It should work if you directly use recent parent sonarqube image. So if the Dockerfile metioned in the question does not work, you have a different problem.

See commit [80366e3419d698b4bba4447f153418ef64b3b705](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/commit/80366e3419d698b4bba4447f153418ef64b3b705) for more info.

> Remove volume for "conf", "logs" and "extensions" directories
>   Explicit declaration of volume is appropriate only for data stored by
>   application, volume for configurable things is almost never
>   appropriate (see docker-library/official-images#2437).
>
> This reverts commit 69fca2e. And additionally removes declaration of
>   volume for "extensions" directory.

Answer (score 1):

*Before SonarQube 5.6*, plugins are stored in a volume, so the appropriate command is (after starting the sonarqube container):

```
wget https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-auth-github-plugin/sonar-auth-github-plugin-1.2.jar -P `docker inspect -f '{{ (index .Mounts 1).Source }}' sonarqube`/plugins
docker restart sonarqube
```